# ActionMailer fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I get a no method error when trying to send out email with ActionMailer

```
NoMethodError in OrdersController#deliver
undefined method `client' for #<OrdersController:0x007fdc22aa4938>
```

My Mailer

```
 class OrdersMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 def email_copy_of_order_to_client(order)
    @order = order
    @client = @order.client
    mail(:to => @client.email, :subject => "Your order")
  end
```

Of course through the console I get what I want

```
  Order.last.client
    Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY "orders"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  => #<Client id: 3, name: "Test Client", address1: "", address2: "", city: ""...`
```

EDITED

```
class OrdersController < InheritedResources::Base
def deliver
@email = OrdersMailer.email_copy_of_order_to_client(self).deliver

respond_to do |format|
  if @email.valid?
    format.html { redirect_to order, notice: 'Order was successfully sent.' }
  else
    format.html { render action: "show", alert: 'An error occured. Please try again.' }
  end
end
end
```

Order#show view

```
<%= pill_button_link_to "Send Order by Email", deliver_order_path(@order) %>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please see above I pasted all the code. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mailer wants an Order as its argument:

```
class OrdersMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def email_copy_of_order_to_client(order)
    #...
```

but you're giving it an instance of *OrderController*:

```
class OrdersController < InheritedResources::Base
  def deliver
    @email = OrdersMailer.email_copy_of_order_to_client(self).deliver
    #...
```

That `self` is an instance of the controller, not an instance of Order. Hence your error message about OrdersController:

```
undefined method `client' for #<OrdersController:0x007fdc22aa4938>
```

You probably want something like this in your `deliver`:

```
def deliver
  order = Order.find(params[:id])
  # check access/ownership/... on order
  @email = OrdersMailer.email_copy_of_order_to_client(order).deliver
  #...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm. Was in Whistler a couple months ago fellow Canadian. Cheers.

Comment: @Gaelle: Cheers, eh. We had snow this morning, woo hoo!

Comment: Can't wait to get snow here in Ott.